# Difference between .on('click') and .off('click').on('click')

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

What is the use or difference of combining `.off` with `.click`?

```
$('#link').off('click').on('click',function(){});
```

vs.

```
$('#link').on('click',function(){});
```

What are the advantages of **combining** them?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This adds a new `click` event handler:

```
$('#link').on('click', function(){});
```

This removes all existing `click` event handlers that were attached with `.on()` (if any) and then adds a new `click` event handler:

```
$('#link').off('click').on('click', function(){});
```

Comment: your answer was simple and understandable. But this `.off` behaviour  can be achieved using `event.preventdefault()` right. ?

Comment: Well, not really. Where do you want to put `event.preventdefault()`?

Comment: If there is any other `click`  event handler in my current `click` - I can prevent it by `event.preventdefault()` right.? what are the differents.?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only prevents the default action of an element (e.g. a `submit` button submitting the form, or a link element loading the URL). It doesn't prevent any previously attached `click` events.

Comment: Especially helpful to include the off if the code is called often. Or else you could be attaching multiple `.on('click')` handlers.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `.one('click')`

Answer (score 3):

From the jquery documentation,

> The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with
>   .on(). See the discussion of delegated and directly bound events on
>   that page for more information. Calling .off() with no arguments
>   removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers
>   can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names,
>   namespaces, selectors, or handler function names. When multiple
>   filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must
>   match for the event handler to be removed.

In your question,

```
$('#link').off('click').on('click',function(){});
```

It will simply remove any previous event handler attached to the event and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

We use `$('#link').on('click',function(){});` when we know that there's no other click function is already bind to this element or even if another click function is a bind, then that's not hindering our click function. We use .off to unbind(stop) click functionality from all places for this element and then we use .on click to bind only our click functionality.