# Checkbox not working normally in case of event.preventDefault and just working when using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, settimeout, preventdefault

I was just going through a scenario where I needed to customize a checkbox so that should not be checked instantly, rather,

1. Show a confirm box, when a user tries to check a checkbox.
2. If the user clicks Yes, the checkbox is checked.
3. On click of No, checkbox does not change and remains unchecked.

While working on that, I used preventDefault followed by stopPropagation to stop the checkbox from following default behavior and make it checked or unchecked conditionally.

In the following snippet, the checkbox is getting checked at first, but then it is not un-checking, given the code is working fine with setTimeout but not without it. Following is the mockup:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chkbx').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    showConfirmation($checkbox.is(':checked') ? 1 : 0);
  });

  function showConfirmation(s_checked) {
    // Why this if block is making checkbox checked 
    if (s_checked) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#chkbx').val(1);
        $('#chkbx').prop('checked', true);
      }, 3000);
      // While a similar code without delay is not working
    } else {
      $('#chkbx').val(0);
      $('#chkbx').prop('checked', false);
    }
    return true;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbx" name="chkbx" />
```

Please help me understand, what is going wrong here due to which the code is not unchecking the checkbox when not using setTimeout.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML.

Comment: What is the purpose of `$('#chkbx').off('click').on('click', function(e) {`? Since you have this in `document.ready()` there would not be any reason to call `.off` if you are just going to immediately call `.on()` on the same element.

Comment: Added HTML part and JS FIDDLE link as well @ScottMarcus

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is to remove (IF) any existing event handler currently associated. As the code I am sharing here is a very tiny part of what we are doing in the actual code base. You will find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136443/difference-between-onclick-and-offclick-onclick

Comment: I understand what `off().on()` is for, but I don't think you understand that `document.ready()` fires as soon as the DOM is ready, at which point, there won't be any registered handlers, so it's useless to use it there. If you do have registered handlers when `document.ready()` fires, then simply alter your code so that you don't since you appear to not want any.

Comment: Also, there is no need to link to your code on 3rd party sites. Just place it into a Stack Snipper (the `{}` button while you are composing your question) and it will run right here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Okay. Didn't knew about Stack Snipper. Thanks for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231553/discussion-between-divyang-and-scott-marcus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` method prevents default action. In the case of clicking a checkbox, the default action is toggling its `checked` state, which is getting prevented in the code in question. With `setTimeout` the code is actually getting executed after the click event has finished, so preventDefault is not being observed.

However, to make this work, you may choose to use `event.preventDefault()` only when you really want to prevent the checkbox toggling. Check out the below snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chkbx').on('click', function(e) {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    if($checkbox.is(":checked")) {
      if(confirm('Do you want to check?')) {
        $checkbox.val(1);
      } else {
        // use `preventDefault()` to block checkbox checking when not confirmed
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    } else {
      $checkbox.val(0);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chkbx" name="chkbx" value="0"/> Checkbox Label</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are taking the wrong approach here. Instead of `e.preventDefault()` and timers, you can just disable the checkbox until the "some other button" that you refer to gets pressed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $checkbox = $("#chkbx");
  
  // Simply set up your button click event
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    $checkbox.removeAttr("disabled"); // Enable the checkbox
  });
  
  $checkbox.on("click", showConfirmation);

  function showConfirmation(event) {
    console.log("The checkbox is checked: " + event.target.checked);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click to enable</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbx" name="chkbx" disabled>Some question
```

Comment: I have updated my question so that is should be more clear as in what is actually required to be done here. Please check that. Thanks for the help.